# JPA query for getting list of objects which are in one To Many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have following tables in one to many relationship

```
Class A {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<B> bs;

    public A(Integer id, String name, List<B> bs){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.bs = bs;
    }
}

Class B {

    @ManyToOne
    private A a;

    private String name;
}
```

I wanto to write query to get data of class A along with their bs
e.g 
`Select NEW A(a.id, a.name, a.bs) FROM A a WHERE a.id = 10;`

my constructor is of parameter (Integer id, String name, List bs). But it throws error unnable to locate appropriate constructor.

Can you tell me what mistake I am doing. And is this really possible in JPA

Comment: I am just giving example that constructor calling is done here. well I rename it

Comment: are you sure that `a.bs` in your HQL query is a list of the data you want ? could you point the whole exception ? Also i am not quite sure if your example works in general. Why you are requesting a new constructor in the HQL query ? The class `A` is already a mapped entity , so you could just return `Select a FROM A a WHERE a.id = 10;`

Comment: you cannot put multi-valued fields in the result clause. See JPA spec. If you want to get "B"s for an A then do a query of B where A is a particular value!

Comment: @AntJavaDev We generally use constructor because we don't need all the fields of that entity, so we create object using constructor having required fields only

Comment: .....well check @Abdullah Wasi answer , this might be your issue

Comment: @NeilStockton then I need to hit multiple queries to get data of B for all A's

Comment: If you want for all A's then you simply query all As and fetch the "bs" field and most JPA providers will do that as 2 SQL queries

Comment: @NeilStockton Yes we generally hit multiple queries, but I was just thinking if it is possible in single query

Comment: since you cannot select multi-valued fields in JPQL then do it the other way around ... have B as candidate and select the B and the owning A. That is the only way

Comment: @NeilStockton can you please explain how. Thanks in advance

Comment: Huh? "SELECT b,a FROM B b"

Answer (score 0):

Give the full package name of the class `new A` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you missed the `@JoinColumn` annotation of JPA. Try this:

```
Class A {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="a", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<B> bs;
}

Class B {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="aId") // Link 'aId' foreign key <--
    private A a;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: I have done it entity. Here to minimize code I just didn't write it

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the default constructor to you entities

The query is better like this

```
"Select NEW A(a.id, a.name, a.bs) FROM " + A.class.getSimpleName() + " a WHERE a.id = 10";
```

Also as msagala said you need to the `@JoinColumn(name = "id")`

Comment: and you can't have a multi-valued field in the SELECT (which is what "a.bs" is)

Comment: `"Select a FROM " + A.class.getSimpleName() + " a WHERE a.id = 10";`
And change the fetch type to EAGER

Comment: @BOUALIALI I don't want all fields of object A

Comment: `"Select a.id, a.name, a.bs FROM " + A.class.getSimpleName() + " a WHERE a.id = 10";`
this query will give you the id, the name and the list of B wich is related to the id=10